# Accessing data in a list created using a model in C#

Tags: c#, list

I have created a list using the following model

```
public class Mod{

public int A{get; set;}
public string B{get; set;}
public string C{get; set;}
public DateTime D{get; set;}
}
```

I have created the list as follows;

```
pubic List<Mod> list = new List<Mod>();
```

What I need is to access the values passed through int A and Put an if condition to those values. How can I do that. How can I access the data in that list.

I'm using this list to populate it with data i'm getting from a database table. the condition what I need to use is that if the value in A is larger than 10 then get the count of that.

Comment: It's really unclear what you mean, I'm afraid. What do you mean "the values pass through int A"? What condition do you want? Please clarify.

Comment: `foreach (var item in list)
            {
                if (item.A == somevalue)
                {
                    
                }
            }`?

Comment: Thanks in advance Akbari. I have edited the question. Hope this is helpful